# Sending data from knockout to php

Tags: javascript, php, knockout.js

I created a login function

```
self.login = function() {
    var credentials = {
        email: self.email(),
        pass: self.pass()
    }
    var data = ko.toJS(credentials);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'client/scripts/pages/login/login.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {data: data},
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
}
```

This will send request to php file when the form is submitted.
Here is the login.php code,

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
return $data['email'];
```

When i execute this, the result is  Undefined index: data

I tried JSON.strignify but it is not working. how can I get the email of the user in php?

Comment: Did you try `JSON.strignify` or `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: why do you need to adjust the object at all? cant you just pass it through without going back and forth with JSON?

Comment: JSON.stringify. I tried using no JSON.stringify and JSON.decode but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the following code:

Client-side (JS):

```
$.ajax((<any>{
    type: "POST",
    async: async,
    url: dataServiceBaseUrl + "request.php", //
    data: {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": method,
        "dbname": dbName,
        "params": JSON.stringify(params)
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    },
    error: function() {
    }
}));
```

Server-side (PHP):

```
function process_request() {
    $dbname = $_POST["dbname"];
    $method = $_POST["method"];
    $params = json_decode($_POST["params"], true);
    $result = call_user_func_array("methods::" .  $method, $params);
    return json_encode(array("jsonrpc" => "2.0", "result" => $result, "error" => null, "usename"=>$usename));
}
```

Of course,

```
var data = ko.toJS(credentials);
```

is necessary to get serializable data to sent.